# Compilar varios archivos Typescript hacia una carpeta

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Tengo mi proyecto Angular.
Cada vez que despliego a producción utilizo `ng build`. No sé si toma la ruta del archivo `tsconfig.json` o es una ruta por default.

A su vez tengo otro archivo que se ejecuta una vez por día.
Tiene como nombre `autorun` y es un archivo `.ts`.

En el archivo `autorun` importo algunos archivos de mi proyecto angular y utilizo algunas funciones.

Para compilar y ejecutar mi archivo `autorun` utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
tsc autorun.ts && node autorun.js
```

Esto me genera el archivo js para ejecutar pero a su vez me crea archivos js en todas las partes de mi proyecto donde tenía los archivos importados.

Leí que puedo utilizar el archivo tsconfig.json para poder indicar la ruta correspondiente.
No quiero modificar eso porque como dije al comienzo, es un proyecto angular y no sé si al desplegar en producción eso está enlazado.

Me gustaría guardarlo en una carpeta que se llame `autorun`. En el mismo nivel de jerarquía que `src`.

Pensé algo así como:

```
tsc autorun.ts (ALGUNA FORMA DE INDICAR OUT DIR) && node ./autorun/autorun.js
```

y así lograr que todos los archivos que sean js vayan a esa carpeta.

Comment: haz probado ng build --prod? al ejecutarlo te envía todo el código a main.ts pero no podrás acceder a un externo .js a menos que este esté en la carpeta assets

Comment: Es que el archivo que quiero compilar no tiene nada que ver con angular.
Pero no entiendo si lo de tsconfig afecta a lo de angular en producción.

Comment: el tsconfig es un archivo para configurar el build, versión de typescript, versión de javascript (ECMAScript, ...), etc. estas configuraciónes son de alto nivel, configuraciones generales, las configuraciones al detalle están en angular.json, qué archivos compila, cuales ignora, donde van a parar, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) con el flag `--outDir` se puede especificar una carpeta de salida donde cada dependencia va a ser compilada a JS dentro de esta carpeta.

El comando sería el siguiente:

```bash
tsc autorun.ts --outDir autorun && node autorun/autorun.js
```

Comment: Con esa flag me funcionó. No lograba encontrarlo en ningun lado. Muchisimas gracias. Era lo que quería hacer.